# How do I return a 403 Forbidden in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

I want my controller to return the right HTTP response code when the user lacks permission to view a particular page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Quickie**

If you are using plain JSP views (as is most common), then simply add

```
<% response.setStatus( 403 ); %>
```

somewhere in your view file. At the top is a nice place.

**Detail**

In MVC, i would always set this in the view, and in most cases with Spring-MVC, use the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` to present the correct view in response to a thrown runtime Exception.

For example: create and throw a `PermissionDeniedException` in your controller or service layer and have the exception resolver point to a view file `permissionDenied.jsp`. This view file sets the 403 status and shows the user an appropriate message.

In your Spring bean XML file:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
  <property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="PermissionDeniedException">          
        rescues/permissionDenied
      </prop>
      ... set other exception/view mappings as <prop>s here ...
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultErrorView" value="rescues/general" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

If you need to implement a user login mechanism, take a look at [Spring Security](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/index.html) (formerly Acegi Security).

Comment: Why is the response.setStatus necessary? Following the response (in Tomcat), there seems to be some strage evolution of the http response code of the response - it is first 200 (default), then moves to 404 (for the sake of the argument) when the Spring DispatcherServlet process the handler exception, then, the view is rendered and the code is set to 500 (which is strange), and then, the setStatus does indeed fix the issue by reverting the code of the response back to 404.

Answer (score 61):

You can also just throw

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException("403 returned");
```

This returns a 403 in the response header.

Comment: This works perfectly and should be the accepted answer because it's most flexible.

Comment: @Heady : Not really the best answer because it creates a strong dependency with Spring Security. Joe's answer, to create your own Exception, is the best IMO. I still upvoted that one since it's a decent alternative.

Comment: This returns a 500 for me.

Answer (score 55):

Create an Exception annotated with [@ResponseStatus](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) e.g. like this:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
public class ForbiddenException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Now just throw that Exception in your handler method and the response will have status 403.

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72009693/2160440) from @Largos below if you are using Spring 5+

Answer (score 13):

Using an `ExceptionResolver` is a great way to go, but if you just want this to be view-independent, you could certainly make a call to `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "AdditionalInformationIfAvailable");` in your Controller.

Answer (score 12):

Use `ResponseStatusException` :

```java
@GetMapping("/demo")
public String demo(){
  if (forbidden){
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:
`response.setStatus(403)`.