# Custom page not found and other error webpages in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I want to display a custom 404 page not found error page (among others).  I'm using Spring 3.0 and don't know how to do this..  I know I can specify a jsp page in web.xml to handle 404 errors.  But I want Spring's environment for my error pages.  So I tried simply returning a ModelAndView that's basically an error page.  But the problem there is once I do this:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```

Then the whole request just gets forwarded back to the container's default 404 page.  How are we supposed to handle error pages in Spring 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Servlet 2.4, `response.sendError()` and `response.setStatus()` are treated differently. The former is handled by container, but the latter gives option to provide the response yourself. That means, you have to use  `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)`. Please also see [How do I return a 403 Forbidden in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546/how-do-i-return-a-403-forbidden-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Going to try this, makes sense.  Thanks!