# Which Exception used for authentication failed for REST POST

Tags: java, rest

Which exception used to check the wrong authentication if i am using REST POST service to send a json to another micro service in java/Spring boot.  For Authentication i am using "bearer token".  Is it HttpServerErrorException or HttpCLientException ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you asking there, but usually a failed authentication should result in error `403` which is a client exception.

Answer (score 0):

See the **second** answer for this question: 
["How do I return a 403 forbbiden in spring"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546/how-do-i-return-a-403-forbidden-in-spring-mvc)

You can throw "*AccessDeniedException*" to specify an **authorization problem**. And to clarify, the "*HttpServerErrorException*" is thrown when an internal problem has ocurred (500 status code). The other exception, "*HttpClientException*", is an Java exception, I mean, not from spring-boot, and is a more general one, anyway you can use it too.